Неправильный file_id aiogram 3.13.1 (файл голосового загруженного с пк, распознаётся как документ)
Каким образом можно корректно загрузить файл на сервер телеграм форматом ogg, чтобы получить file_id. Голосовое отправленое путем нажатия на микрофон получает корректный file_id.
А отправленный файл получает этот ид как "документ"
Соответственно когда я полученный file_id отправленного файла ogg использую в другом боте. То получаю ошибку telegram что используемый file_id не является голосовым...

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык
